# What is the difference between Routing in React and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, express-router

I am having trouble understanding the difference between routing in frontend and backend.

My basic understanding is that the React-router will map a component to a URL like:

```
   <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

And the Express-router will map a html-page to a specific route

```
// GET method route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html')
})

// POST method route
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

I always thought the frontend is responsible for creating the views and the backend would map those views to a route. Meaning visiting a route would render the associated template.

I can't wrap my head around how this changes when using React-route and Express-router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, indeed there is difference between them. When you are using **react-router** you use Router and Link components to render the **about** component which will send you the **about page** link.

```
<Link to='/about'>About</Link>
< Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

it's kinda same in **express**, if you render a view like this :

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.render('about.html')
})
```

Let's see, you want your database data on the front-end. If you use normal view engines like ejs, 
handlebars then after finding the data from db you will render them to html or ejs page.

If you are using react for single page application then you don't need react-router. But if your app has multiple pages, then using react-router is good.

See this below example code:

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
// finding the user details from database
  user.find()(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.json(users); //sends the user data
    }
});
```

And now, React have to grab this data from the backend, It can be done by many approaches, I prefer to use **axios** package which is a npm does the same job as FETCH API does.

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:5000/about')
      .then(response => {
           this.setState({users: response.data}); //this reponse.data is coming from backend
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
 })
```

So now, you see react-router-dom is not the same as express routing. 
`< Route path="/about" component={About} />`, you can give this address 
anything you like i.e `"/details"` etc. You only have to give `axios.get(endpoint)` address as the same as express endpoint. But you must have to use `Link` from react-router-dom to going to the exact endpoint path of express routing.

`<Link to='/about'>About</Link>` should be same as `app.get('/about',.....)`

Hopefully, this will resolve your issues about understanding react-router and express routing.

Comment: So is what you're saying  -React routing is for mapping a component to a URL and Express routing is to expose REST API endpoints  to be accessed using the HTTP protocol (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE). When a route is hit on the frontend it will render the mapped componenet which will call the exposed REST API for the resource it needs (e.g JSON data from the DB)

Comment: so does that mean, frontend routes (in URL) can be different than backend routes of the backend, e.g frontend might display `/about/me` while the actual endpoint on the backend is `/about/user` etc